# How to run two Keycloak instances parallel on windows?

Tags: keycloak, saml, service-provider

I want to run two keycloak admin panel parallel on different port for saml one panel work as a idp and second is work as a sp so how can i run two parrallel panel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset Parameter to run it on a different port.
For example standalone.bat  -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset 1000 will start an instance running on https-port 9443